# Set constructor argument to null for a request scoped bean, if not within request

Tags: java, spring

Let's say I have a bean:

```
@Component
@RequestScope
class MyBean {
    private final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Autowired
    public MyBean(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        this.httpServletRequest = httpServletRequest;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getProperties() { .. }
}
```

In the above bean, `getProperties` does not use `httpServletRequest` at all, and I need to call the method in the bootstrapping phase, which is outside of a request context. Doing so, obviously gives me the error `No thread-bound request found ...`. Is there a way to ask spring to make the value `null` if not in a request context?

Comment: It looks to me that you're breaking the single responsibility rule for this class. Maybe some extra details are needed, but if you create a new instance (manually). Maybe you should create a bean with the properties which has a singleton scope and inject it on `MyBean` or wherever you need these properties.

Comment: This seems odd to me... It's constructor injected, so `httpServletRequest` is injected at instantiation, and it's a final field. But an `HttpServletRequest` is created each time a request is made, so how can the final qualifier work?

Comment: As for the question, you can look at `@Autowired(required=false)` and see if that does it.

Comment: It's a request scoped bean, so for each request you have a new bean instance. So the final is not a problem here.
To the question itself: So basically `getProperties()` has an application scope? Then i would move it to a bean with application scope

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Basically, `MyBean` is proxied to a class `MyBean$$EnhancedBySpringCGLib` (or something similar) and an internal field is set of type `MyBean`. It is this internal field that is swapped with new instances which are created on every requests, so the final constraint is never violated.

Comment: @dunni I agree, and also with @Alex. But if anyone was looking for a solution, marking the method as `final` makes Spring not look for a scoped proxy and it works. But, yeah, wouldn't recommend it.